# Export Jar file in Netbeans,change position of icons/buttons or disappear icons

Tags: java, netbeans, jar, export

I made a project and when i run from Netbeans it runs well without problems.
When, i export .jar file (Shift-F11) and run the jar file,then one from my options on my projects does not work good,not as algorithm but it changes the position of buttons or do not show important icons. Other options runs good as i want.
Can anyone help me?
Thank you,

Comment: Anyone who can help,because it is very important for my project !
Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem that you have with icons not displayed is because they are not imported to your project, but instead are set as external images. Hope helps, though it's late I guess.